# Initial quota start "fail" after root partition resize

Tags: server, webserver

So i wanted to take little space away from root to put into boot partition. I used kde partition to resize my logical volume, but now sever won't boot and freeze during post.
First error starts at initial quota start fail, probably because of disk resize its quotas are messed up preventing boot ?
Please help really need this webserver back online asap !

Comment: It is odd your system will not boot due to that error. To fix that error boot to recovery mode and trun quota off https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2302458 . It would help if we had more information about why it does not boot.

Comment: Id love to get you more :) what would you like to see? System won't boot have to use liveusb

Comment: Because that's not really where it freezes, but that's the first error I see during post

Comment: Where does it freeze ?

Comment: Something abot time sychronization i think is the last one, unfortunately I had to leave to work now :(

Comment: If you could coach me on how to get the info you need for why it won't boot if really appreciate :) when I get home tonight I will get  anything you might advise :)

Comment: We need more information. You can try booting to recovery mode or boot a live usb and see if you can check the logs. You may need to reverse the changes you made.